# Neither the_content() or have_post is showing content (posts) on my site

Tags: php, wordpress, file-get-contents

Here is a link to my page:
http://list.thorsteinnhelgason.is/index.php/blog/

This is my code:

```
<div class="container">

    <div id="content">

         <?php 
        while ( have_posts() )
        {
            the_post();
    ?>
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php
        }
    ?>

        </div>
```

This is a loop from my Single.php file, which is not showing any post content at my post site.  Do I need to call the action in some other template (functions.php e.g) in order to get the content of my posts?  Or what could be the reason for it not to work?  Hope you can help me...

Comment: `the_title` should be _inside the loop_.  `get_template_part` is attempting to load another template file, so without knowing what is inside of _that_ file, it's impossible to tell.  For fun, why don't you add `the_title(); the_content();` just _before_ `get_template_part('content');` and see what happens.

Comment: can you update the question with your whole file? as cale_b said, it has to be in the loop. For all we know you're calling that above the container div or you arent using it at all

Comment: I simplified the code a little, but still it is not working;
`<div id="content">
  
       <?php 

            while ( have_posts() )

            {

                the_post();

        ?>

        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>

        <?php the_content(); ?>

        <?php

            }

        ?>

    
   </div>`

Answer (score 0):

Create an 'if' statement to check if posts exists (before your 'while'). And then remember to close/end your 'while' and 'if' loops.

```
<div class="container">
 <div id="content">

   <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

      <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
      <?php the_content(); ?>

    <?php 
      endwhile; 
      endif; 
     ?>

 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @ianbeans Unfortunately this does not work either.  Could there be some other settings og thinks that has an affect on the post not showing?

Comment: There could be a hundred things that is preventing the content from rendering - I was just fixing your code. I suggest following these tutorials to learn WordPress. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oTRZYnYQlmo&t=1054s

Comment: Thanks - I will look at it.  Here is a link to the page:  http://list.thorsteinnhelgason.is/index.php/blog/
 - just if you can see right away if something is blocking.